# Codeigniter Getting only last Data from ID

Tags: phpmyadmin, codeigniter-3

The issue is that, I am only getting the last data from the above function. In my database, I have four categories listed in my database but only receiving the data from the last query. How can I get rid of this? I have tried multiple variations over here.

I have also tried normal sql queries with the same, but I got the data from last id only.

```
 foreach($category as $cat){

     $cat_id = $cat->id;
     $data['catalog'] = $this->homemodel->getCatalog($cat_id);
 }
```

Comment: Hi, can you try declaring your `$data` variable to array? Just like `$data = array();`

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
$i = 0;
foreach($category as $cat)
{
   $cat_id = $cat->id;
   $data['catalog'] = $this->homemodel->getCatalog($cat_id);
   $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace Your Code with below code

```
foreach($category as $cat){

     $cat_id = $cat->id;
     $data['catalog'][] = $this->homemodel->getCatalog($cat_id);
 }
```